# Searching using Windows Exporer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, search

I try to search for a string in a file, typing `Distribution Statement A` in the Windows Explorer search box.

But the search finds files with `Distribution` in them. It finds files with `Statement` in them. But it finds NONE with the whole string in it.  Is special punctuation needed to get it to search for an entire string?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### Is special punctuation needed to get it to search for an entire string?

No. But you can use the `content:` search operator as follows.

Enter the following in the Windows Explorer search box:

```
Content:"Distribution Statement A"
```